# Hibernate Search NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Just a quick line to see if anyone has had a similar problem to this?

I have checked that I am using the dependencies that are required in the project setup but am getting this error when I try to use createIndexer():

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.Session.setDefaultReadOnly(Z)V
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.EntityConsumerLuceneworkProducer.run(EntityConsumerLuceneworkProducer.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.run(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:107)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Cheers,
rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session.setDefaultReadOnly()` was added in Hibernate 3.5. Perhaps your version of Hibernate Search is not compatible with your version of Hibernate.

See [Hibernate Compatibility Matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix).

Comment: You were right, I had a 2nd level dependancy that was bringing in a hibernate 3.2.6 jar.  Now I have explicitly stopped that it is using the correct 3.5 jar.  Thanks for your quick reply :) Rob